# Permalink in website

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a website, Now I want to implement a permalink feature in that like, http://mywebsite.com/sougata should sougata's web page. For that one I have used Wrote a restful service using Spring MVC which is returning my desired page. 
Described it like
@RequestMapping(value="/{username}",method = RequestMethod.GET)

Now problem is when I want to call any other service this webservice get called. Is there way way to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

Design your RESTful URLs properly.  The url **http://mywebsite.com/{anything-here}** definitely matches your controller method. And the url **http://mywebsite.com/{anything-here}/{something-here}** will not match the same controller method.

I would prefer you to have below url mapping for your permalinks 
**http://mywebsite.com/perm/{anything-here}**

Comment: You are right. But I want to have url like twitter say http://twitter.com/sougata would give sougata's page and http://twitter.com/about would provide twitter's about page